# When to use implicit differentiation?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

When a problem is expressed like this $F(x,y)$ then you are asked to find $F_x(x,y)$

My understand is that means you need to find the partial derivative of $x$, which means $y$ is held and treated as constant ?  Is this correct or does it need to use that funny little partial derivative symbol ?

Thanks,

Comment: arrghh, sorry I stuffed up my question, if you're asked to find $F'(x,y)/dx$ then you use implicit differentiation and $y$ would become $y'(x) dx$ right ?

Comment: It will be wise if you upvote to those who have helped you as the appreciation to their help. Don't also forget to accept the answer that you think the *best*.

Answer (score 1):

You we describing "partial differentiation", not "implicit differentiation". The symbols $$F_x(x,y)$$ and $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y)$$ mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your opinion is correct: $F_x$ means the derivative of $F$ with respect to the $x$ variable, and $y$ is kept constant. It is just an alternative notation to
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}, \quad D_xF, \quad \partial_x F, \quad \partial_1 F.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$F_x(x,y)$, $F_y(x,y)$, and even just $F_x$ or $F_y$ are all notations for a partial derivative with respect to the subscript.